# How to assign key from list for dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have to write a method, using a dictionary, which takes a list `a` and returns a list containing the elements of `a` that occur once and elements should appear in the same order as their first occurrence in `a`. Do I think in right direction? This is my code:

```
def only_once(a):
    d = {}
    for i in a:
        d['value'] = i
    m = range(len(a))
    for num in m:
        d['key'] = num
    return d.value
```

How to take elements from list `a` and make values?

Comment: Do you have to use a dictionary?

Comment: Dictionaries don't preserve order, it might not be a good idea to user dicts here if you want to preserve order of occurrence.

Comment: Yes I have to use dictionaries. Maybe inside my function, just to check if something in it. But dictionary has to be here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a naïve solution. It pretty much uses a dict as a `set`, which is silly, because python has sets. But hey.

```
def only_once(a):
  d = {}
  for i in a:
    d.setdefault(i,0)
    d[i] += 1
  return [i for i in a if d[i] == 1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I need, and moreover I understand it :)

Answer (score 2):

[`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) has a [recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) for this task:

```
def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in ifilterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element
```

BTW, since you want the order to be the same, a dictionary won't help here. A `dict` doesn't maintain any order.

Comment: `seen_add = seen.add` What's this for?

Comment: @BartoszKP Creating a copy of function `add`

Comment: @RohitJain I understand what it does, but why would you do that?

Comment: @user2847624 Do you really want to use a dictionary for this task? But why?

Comment: @user2847624 If the dictionary is mandatory, just use it instead of `set` and store `None` for the values.

Comment: @BartoszKP No idea, why they have used. That seems to be useless there.

Comment: It's not useless – it removes the lookup chain for that method in the loop.

Comment: I don't want, I have to. Because my task says "use dictionaries' I don't have choice. Okay, do you know how to do it without saving the same order? I will lose a part of mark, but anyway, I will have something

Comment: @user2847624 I guess you would have to use an `OrderedDict` for that.

Comment: @user2847624 See this - http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution using dict comprehension and sorting dict keys by corresponding values:

```
def only_once(a):
   # create the dictionary using dict comprehension;
   # add to the dictionary only if the number of occurences
   # equals one
   d = {x:a.index(x) for x in a if a.count(x) == 1}

   # retrieve the dictionary keys as list and sort them by the value
   # of their assigned dictionary values
   return sorted(d.keys(), key = d.get)
```

but I agree that dict is not the most fortunate choice of datastructure for solving this problem.